# Trouble with #include, C++

Tags: c++, include

I know this is a common problem, but I am pretty sure there is no error with how I include the files.

I'll give you the basic files.

### Main.cpp:

```
#include "GameState.h"
#inlcude "Timer.h"

int main ( int argc, char** argv ) {
```

### GameState.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Character.h"
```

### Character.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Setup.h"
```

### Setup.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_main.h"
#include "SDL_image.h"
```

### Error report:

```
Error   1   error LNK2005: "void __cdecl apply_surface(int,int,struct SDL_Surface *,struct SDL_Surface *,struct SDL_Rect *)" (?apply_surface@@YAXHHPAUSDL_Surface@@0PAUSDL_Rect@@@Z) already defined in Character.obj   C:\Users\Jim\Documents\C++\herorpg\herorpg\Main.obj
Error   2   error LNK2005: "bool __cdecl init(struct SDL_Surface * &)" (?init@@YA_NAAPAUSDL_Surface@@@Z) already defined in Character.obj   C:\Users\Jim\Documents\C++\herorpg\herorpg\Main.obj
Error   3   error LNK2005: "bool __cdecl load_files(struct SDL_Surface * * const)" (?load_files@@YA_NQAPAUSDL_Surface@@@Z) already defined in Character.obj C:\Users\Jim\Documents\C++\herorpg\herorpg\Main.obj
Error   4   error LNK2005: "struct SDL_Surface * __cdecl load_image(char *)" (?load_image@@YAPAUSDL_Surface@@PAD@Z) already defined in Character.obj    C:\Users\Jim\Documents\C++\herorpg\herorpg\Main.obj
Error   6   error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found   C:\Users\Jim\Documents\C++\herorpg\Debug\herorpg.exe
```

Is there anything wrong with what I'm including? If you think more information is required, I'll post the full code. Just seemed like a nuisance before.

Comment: you aren't linking the SDL library.

Comment: Seems like you're defining functions in your header files. They should be declared in the header files and then defined in the corresponding `.cpp` file.

Comment: Are you not supposed to define functions in a header file? I didn't know that would result in error. And I'm pretty sure SDL is linked properly.

Comment: @JimHurley Normally, you *declare* functions in headers and *define* them in .cpp files.

Comment: But that doesn't solve my problem. In fact, if I comment out #include "Setup.h" in character and fiddle with it so it doesn't require Setup.h, the program compiles without error. But I have to include it.

Comment: The specific answer of @sftrabbit helped me understand the relation. Sorry I doubted you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ has a rule called the *one definition rule*. Among other things, this rule specifies that there cannot be multiple definitions of a function across your program. You can't have two translation units that both define a function, otherwise you break this rule. You can think of a translation unit as a `.cpp` file with all of its headers included into the appropriate places.

So if you have a header file, `foo.h`, that looks like this:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

int foo() { return 5; }

#endif
```

And then you include this header in two or more `.cpp` files, each of the translation units will have their own definition. This violates the one definition rule.

To fix this, your header should give a function declaration like so:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

int foo();

#endif
```

Then, in the corresponding `foo.cpp` file, give a definition for the function:

```
#include "foo.h"

int foo() { return 5; }
```

This means that only the `foo.cpp` translation unit will have a definition of `foo`. Any uses of `foo` in other translation units will be *linked* to that definition.

An alternative is to declare the function as `inline`, as in:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

inline int foo() { return 5; }

#endif
```

The reason this is allowed is because each translation *must* be able to see the definition of such a function to be able to inline it. However, I don't recommend using `inline` all willy-nilly.

Comment: Thank you for being so specific.

Comment: He allready has `#pragma once` so he shouldn't need an extra inclusion guard ( ? )

Comment: @olevegard I was giving my own samples.

Answer (score 0):

Linker errors are not caused by `#include` errors. Linker errors usually happens when the compilers can't find the definition of something. Or if it finds multiple definitions ( such as in this case )

Check if you are linking with multiple SDL libraries or if you have defined the functions yourself somwhere in the code

Comment: The multiple definitions were a result of the include files.

Answer (score 0):

possible reason:

1. define functions in header files.  functions should only be defined in .cpp file.
2. looped header files including.  like:  a.h includes b.h,  b.h includes c.h, and c.h includes a.h.  Sometime the looped including is not obvious, but it does happen.    "#pragma once" can only prevents one header file from being included more than once, but cannot prevent looped including.  To solve this problem, using "forward declaration" to replace some #include statements.

some links about forward declaration:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration

[When can I use a forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f432x8c6(v=vs.80).aspx